# How to open current submenu? In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNyLzB)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a>Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Menu 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu-1">
      <li>link1</li>
      <li>link2</li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
   <li>
    <a>Menu 3</a>
    <ul class="submenu-1">
      <li>link1</li>
      <li>link2</li>
    </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$('.menu a').click(function(){
   var subMenu  = $(this).closest("li").find("submenu-1");
   if(subMenu){
     alert("open current sub menu")
   }


 });
```

What I want to do it's the next thing...for example:

1.If you click on the `"menu2"` to open its submenu.

2.If you click on the `"menu3"` to hide submenu for `"menu2"` and open submmenu for "menu3"

You can send your a short example and tell me please how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery `show()/toggle()`

```
   $('.menu a').click(function(){
   var subMenu  = $(this).next(".submenu-1");
   if(subMenu.length >0){
     $(".submenu-1").not(subMenu).hide();
    $(subMenu).toggle();
   }


 });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqmpqP

Comment: and first you have to hide? Now open both ... I want to be just one open

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you. much cleaner.

```
$('.menu a').click(function(){
  $(".submenu").hide();
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

http://codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/BKRPoE